# R - Plotly issue with multiple lines plotting simple loop

Tags: r, loops, r-plotly

Hi using the code bellow I am not able to generate multiple lines, already tried other solutions as inherit, evauate = TRUE/FALSE and its not showing all the lines. If I use the same code outside the loop it works fine...

```
library("plotly")

test = data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:10,10,rep=TRUE)))
test 

fig <- plot_ly()
for (i in names(test)){
  temp = test[[i]]
  print(temp)
  fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~1:10, y = ~temp, type="scatter", mode = 'lines')
}
fig
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Lb5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. As you are adding the traces inside the loop without using a dataframe as argument, you could avoid the `~` symbol and invoke directly the values. Here the code:

```
library("plotly")

test = data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:10,10,rep=TRUE)))
test 

fig <- plot_ly()
for (i in names(test)){
  temp = test[[i]]
  fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = 1:10, y = temp, type="scatter", mode = 'lines')
}
fig
```

Output:

[image]